# Using folder wildcards to copy files with Python

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I would like to copy the **data** of one specific shapefile from a specific folder ("Grid") to a number of folders containing the name "Country". The country shapefiles would **keep their original name**. Since there are multiple *Country* folders, I thought using a wildcard would be quite useful. The following diagram tries to illustrate what I am doing:

[image: File/folders]

Below is the code I have at the moment where I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120656/directory-listing-in-python) as a guide:

```
import os, sys, glob, shutil

root_dir = "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Test\\"
country_dir = "Country*\\"

#do_some_function

for path, dirname in os.walk(root_dir):
    if country_dir in path:
        for subdirname in dirname:
            if subdirname.startswith('Country'):
                for fname in glob.glob('*.shp'):
                    shutil.copyfile(do_some_function, fname)
```

However, I receive the following error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

Any advice on what I am doing wrong?

---

**EDIT**:

Following @NathanW's suggestion, I've changed the script to the following:

```
import os, sys, shutil

root_dir = "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Test\\"
country_dir = "Country*\\"

#do_some_function

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir + folder_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('*.shp'):
            shutil.copy(do_some_function, file)
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens.

Comment: So just to clear it up, you want a copy of grid into each country folder right?

Comment: I found in the past copying individual shapefile sometimes is problematic and may lead to a corrupt shapefile.  You code only looks like it is copying the .shp of the shpafile, what about, .dbf, .shx...etc?  Instead of using shutil to copy I would suggest using arcpy feature class to feature class method.

Comment: @NathanW - Yes, a copy of grid in each country folder but I would like to keep the **country filename**. I.e. copying Grid.shp to France.shp, the result would be **France.shp**.

Comment: @artwork21 - That's a very good point, thank you! I tend to call QGIS functions in my script which, I guess, automatically creates the .dbf, .shx files. I forgot that `shutil.copy` is purely python :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
import os, glob, shutil
root_dir = "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Test\\"
country_dir = "Country_"
grid_path = "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\Test\Grid\Grid.shp"

# Get all files that constitute the Grid Shapefile
gridShpFiles = glob.glob(grid_path[:-3]+"*")

for path,dirname,files in os.walk(root_dir):
  if country_dir in path:
    for f in gridShpFiles:
      shutil.copy(f, path)
```

Take your time to set paths (lines 2, 3, and 4), I tested the script on GNU/Linux, but Windows paths are always trickier.

As you notice, you can avoid the wildcard; the expression `if country_dir in path:` does the work.

Finally, as @atrwork21 mentioned, you need to take all Shapefile files into account. That's what the second block does.

Answer (score 2):

`os.walk` returns a tuple of three values:

`for path, dirs, files in os.walk()`

Also consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/use-a-glob-to-find-files-recursively-in-python